# Can't add Android platform in Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova

here is the information shown in my commandline:

```
$ cordova platform add android
Error during untar for /home/aqib/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/5.2.2/package.tgz: 
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/home/aqib/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/5.2.2/package/.npmignore'

Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/home/aqib/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/5.2.2/package/.npmignore'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the platform as **Administrator**.

If you are using Linux run as:

```
sudo cordova platform add android
```

If you are working on windows open the `cmd` with right click and then choose **Run as administrator**. After that you install your cordova with:

```
cordova platform add android
```